# Why not input array give result in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using this code to get result using AngularJS

```
<div ng-repeat="item in CartItems" class="row">
    <input type="hidden" ng-init="cart.premium[$index] = item.bid_amount" ng-model="cart.premium[$index]">
</div>
```

In controller

```js
app.controller('ShoppingCart', function($scope, MenuData, $rootScope, $http, RouteData, MyCache) {
           $scope.route =   RouteData.url;
            $scope.user_detail = $rootScope;
            var total = 0;

            // Cached data
            $scope.msg = 1;
            $scope.CartItems = MyCache.get('CartItems');
            $scope.total = MyCache.get('total');
            $scope.itemsCount = MyCache.get('itemsCount');

            // data is not in cache then get from server
            if(!$scope.CartItems) {

               
            };
      
      $scope.cart = {};
           
            $scope.check_out    =   function(){
               
                if($scope.cart.total <= 9999){
                    alert($.param($scope.cart));

                    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI($scope.createPayment1($scope.cart.total), $scope.onSuccesfulPayment, $scope.onUserCanceled);

                }

            };
```

but it cannot give any result. While when we do

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="test[]" value="test">
```

give the required result.

How can I achieve this thing with AngularJS?

Comment: is this inside of a `ng-repeat`?

Comment: yes this is in ng-repeat

Comment: what is `cart`? what is `CartItems`?

Comment: Try `ng-repeat="item in CartItems track by $index"`. You could also just use `ng-model="item.bid_amount"` if it is bound to the same array.

Comment: Otherwise, please share some controller code that define the `cart.premium` and `CartItems`

Comment: @lante CartItems is an data object return from controller.

Comment: Still don't see `cart.premium` and `CartItems` in your controller

Comment: That is the full code for the controller? what is `createPayment1`? How are `cart` and `CartItems` filled? Help us to help you

Comment: this is `Create Payment` function `$scope.createPayment1 = function (total) {
// for simplicity use predefined amount

            var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails("1.50", "0.40", "0.05");
            var payment = new PayPalPayment(total, "USD", "Buy Out", "Sale", paymentDetails);
            return payment;
        };`

Comment: @devqon `cart.premium` is ng-model. I get all data using `$scope.cart` in controller

Comment: Please recreate (with only the relevant parts) in a jsfiddle